# Ansible beginner - List object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: ansible

I have an issue with looping on vars,

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars:
    user: 
      - name: "neito"
        pubkey: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/vsphere_vm.pub') }}"
        privkey: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/vsphere_vm') }}"
  tasks:
    - name: "Add SSH public key"
      authorized_key:
        user: "{{ item.name }}"
        key: "{{ item.pubkey }}"
      loop:
        - "{{ user }}"
```

when running this playbook I have the following error :
`The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'name'`

The `{{ item.name }}` seems to be undefined for Ansible, I guess I'm missing something obvious here but I can't find what. (I was following [this get started post](https://blog.risingstack.com/getting-started-with-ansible-infrastructure-automation/)

Edit 1 :

By declaring the vars like following it works :

```yaml
vars:
    user:
      {
        name: "neito",
        pubkey: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/vsphere_vm.pub') }}",
        privkey: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/vsphere_vm') }}",
      }
```

Could someone still point me out why the first syntax didn't work?

Answer (score 6):

The problem was the `-` dash in front of the `"{{ user }}"`:

```yaml
loop:
  - "{{ user }}"
```

Needs to be :

```yaml
loop: "{{ user }}"
```

Comment: This answer points to the real problem. This one shall be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Please check the [loops documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#id4):

> You can define the list in a variables file, or in the ‘vars’ section of your play, then refer to the name of the list in the task:
>
> ```yaml
> loop: "{{ somelist }}"
> ```

If you modify your original task to:

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: "Add SSH public key"
    authorized_key:
      user: "{{ item.name }}"
      key: "{{ item.pubkey }}"
    loop: "{{ user }}"
```

you should be good to go.

Comment: This answer doesn't show the reason for the problem. The code works though.

Comment: Since documentation suggests that using `- "{{ a list }}"` is not the proper way, i guess there is no point analyzing it any further. Perhaps the `loop` is more strict on the syntax of the input variable, than `with_items` is.

Comment: `with_items: "{{ whatever }}"` is equivalent to `loop: "{{ whatever | flatten(levels=1) }}"`. This is why it will work if you pass a list of lists. Loop will not accept that on its own. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-items

Answer (score 0):

Originally you defined `user` as a 1-element list. The little dash (`-`) at the beginning denoted an element of a list.

```yaml
user:
  - name: "neito"
    pubkey: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/vsphere_vm.pub') }}"
    privkey: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/vsphere_vm') }}"
# in YAML, the below is equivalent to the above
user:
  [
    {
      name: "neito",
      pubkey: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/vsphere_vm.pub') }}",
      privkey: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/vsphere_vm') }}"
    }
  ]
```

The brackets are alternative syntax to the dashes.
On a similar note, curly braces are also an alternative to specifying each property on a new line, with increased indentation. So you could rewrite your second example in the following way:

```yaml
user:
  name: "neito"
  pubkey: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/vsphere_vm.pub') }}"
  privkey: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/vsphere_vm') }}" """)
```

Thanks to the fact that the brackets and curly braces are also valid in YAML, you can actually parse JSON files as YAML and it will work 100% (but not the other way around).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and extra infos.

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem. In addition to this, the proposed dictionary does not serve the purpose of iterating the users.

Comment: @VladimirBotka thanks for your feedback. I agree that iterating users would probably make sense here, but it wasn't clear from the question that OP wanted `user` to be a list (perhaps in such case it should have been called `users`?). If you take a look at the tutorial OP is following, that tutorial uses `loop: `...`- '"{{ user }}"'` all over the place.